# How to check if data has already been previously used

Tags: python

I have a python script that retrieves the newest 5 records from a mysql database and sends email notification to a user containing this information.
I would like the user to receive only new records and not old ones.
I can retrieve data from mysql without problems...
I've tried to store it in text files and compare the files but, of course, the text files containing freshly retrieved data will always have 5 records more than the old one.

So I have a logic problem here that, being a newbie, I can't tackle easily.

Using lists is also an idea but I am stuck in the same kind of problem.

The infamous 5 records can stay the same for one week and then we can have a new record or maybe 3 new records a day.

It's quite unpredictable but more or less that should be the behaviour.

Thank you so much for your time and patience.

Comment: Is there any way you can tag the records in the database itself. One boolean field called 'retrieved' or an integer field called 'times_retrieved' would do this. You select on the ones that are false or 0, and then update them promptly after retrieval. Only if your database updates are really fast, this may not work, but that appears not to be the case for you.

Comment: Do these records have a time stamp or monotonically increasing unique id?

Comment: Unique id, @MartijnPieters :)

Comment: @Pitto: Then just track the last ID you've sent an email for. Any records you see next time with a higher ID are new. You can store the last-seen ID anywhere, even in a new table in the database itself.

Comment: Simple, fast, classy. Being a newbie is a sad thing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you assigning a unique incrementing ID to each record?  If you are, you can create a separate table that holds just the ID of the last record fetched, that way you can only retrieve records with IDs greater than this ID.  Each time you fetch, you could update this table with the new latest ID.

Let me know if I misunderstood your issue, but saving the last fetched ID in the database could be a solution.